# How to adjust x limits in subplot without shrinking colorbar

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a set of subplots that each require a colorbar. If I plot each subplot without setting the x limits, the x-axis extends past the domain of my data and shows a lot of white space. I'm using this code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.mlab import griddata
from numpy import ma
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable

def plot_threshold(ax):
    """ plot boundary condition (solid) and
        extrapolated condition(dotted)"""
    x = np.arange(0,10,.5)
    slide= Threshold(x)
    ax.plot(slide[0], slide[1], 'r-',
             linewidth=2)
    ex_slide = Extrapolated_threshold(x)
    ax.plot(ex_slide[0], ex_slide[1], 'r:')

def make_subplot(ax, x, y, zdata, title):
    ax.set_title(title, size =14)
    CS = ax.tricontourf(x, y, zdata, 100, cmap=clrmap)
    plot_threshold(ax)

     #TROUBLESOM LINE BELOW
    plt.xlim(0,xmax)

    # create divider for existing axes instance
    divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)
    # append axes to rhe right of ax, with 5% width of ax
    cax1 = divider.append_axes('right', size='4%', pad = 0.1)
    # create color bar in the appneded axes
    cbar = plt.colorbar(CS, cax=cax1)

clrmap = plt.cm.viridis

# Three subplots, stacked vertically
fig, axarr = plt.subplots(3, figsize =(8,10), sharex='col')
make_subplot(axarr[0], x, y, z1, "Plot 1")  
make_subplot(axarr[1], x, y, z2, 'Plot 2')     
make_subplot(axarr[2], x, y, z3, 'Plot 3')
```

If I add `plt.xlim()` to the `make_subplot` function the colorbar of the top two subplots become extremely narrow and unreadable. The third subplot's colorbar is unaffected.

Removing the `plt.xlim()` from `make_subplot` and adding it beneath the function calls, like this:

```
make_subplot(axarr[0], x, y, z1, "Plot 1")
plt.xlim(0,14)
make_subplot(axarr[1], x, y, z2, 'Plot 2')
plt.xlim(0,14)     
make_subplot(axarr[2], x, y, z3, 'Plot 3')
plt.xlim(0,14)
```

does not adjust the x limits AND squishes the colorbars.

1) Why are the colorbars not all affected the same way by the line in `make_subplots`?

2) How can I adjust the x limits while keeping happy colorbars?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
make_subplot(axarr[0], x, y, z1, "Plot 1")
plt.xlim(0,14)
make_subplot(axarr[1], x, y, z2, 'Plot 2')
plt.xlim(0,14)     
make_subplot(axarr[2], x, y, z3, 'Plot 3')
plt.xlim(0,14)
```

try

```
make_subplot(axarr[0], x, y, z1, "Plot 1")
axarr[0].set_xlim(0,14)
make_subplot(axarr[1], x, y, z2, 'Plot 2')
axarr[1].set_xlim(0,14)     
make_subplot(axarr[2], x, y, z3, 'Plot 3')
axarr[2].set_xlim(0,14)
```

I suppose `plt.xlim` is acting on the colorbar axis because it is the current axis at the time it is called. Calling `plt.xlim` on the axis your data is displayed on (i.e. `axarr[i]`) should fix that up.

Comment: You were right about using `set_xlim` but it needed to be used inside of `make_subplot` as `ax.set_xlim(0,14)`.